Not able to install kerberos package in docker container
I identified that the kerberos package in package.json was causing Docker builds to fail. After removing "kerberos": "^2.1.1", the build succeeded. The problem is isolated to the kerberos package. The kerberos package should install correctly in the Docker container without errors for a complete build. I've mentioned the Dockerfile, package.json in the below
Docker file:
FROM node:lts-alpine3.20
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache python3 make g++ krb5-dev

ENV PYTHON /usr/bin/python3

RUN npm install --force
COPY ./ ./
CMD ["npm", "run", "dockerStart"]

Error:
npm notice
npm error code 1
npm error path /usr/myProject/node_modules/kerberos
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c prebuild-install --runtime napi || node-gyp rebuild
npm error make: Entering directory '/usr/myProject/node_modules/kerberos/build'
npm error make: Leaving directory '/usr/myProject/node_modules/kerberos/build'
npm error prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=4 runtime=napi arch=x64 libc=musl platform=linux)
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm error gyp info using node@20.15.1 | linux | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.7 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm error gyp http GET https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v20.15.1/node-v20.15.1-headers.tar.gz
npm error gyp http 200 https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v20.15.1/node-v20.15.1-headers.tar.gz
npm error gyp http GET https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v20.15.1/SHASUMS256.txt
npm error gyp http 200 https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v20.15.1/SHASUMS256.txt
npm error gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'make',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/usr/myProject/node_modules/kerberos/build/config.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/root/.cache/node-gyp/20.15.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/20.15.1',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/20.15.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/usr/myProject/node_modules/kerberos',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'build',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp info spawn make
npm error gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm error make: printf: Operation not permitted
npm error make: *** [kerberos.target.mk:111: Release/obj.target/kerberos/src/kerberos.o] Error 127
npm error gyp ERR! build error
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:209:23)
npm error gyp ERR! System Linux 5.17.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
npm error gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd /usr/myProject/node_modules/kerberos
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v20.15.1
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-12-02T10_13_54_291Z-debug-0.log

Package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@log4js-node/gelf": "^1.0.2",
    "@log4js-node/smtp": "^1.1.0",
    "amqplib": "^0.10.4",
    "async": "^3.1.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.12",
    "clean-deep": "^3.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.0.0",
    "deep-diff": "^1.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-interceptor": "^1.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
    "gelfy": "^2.0.0",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.4.0",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "kerberos": "^2.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "log4js": "^6.1.0",
    "log4js-json-layout": "^2.2.3",
    "lusca": "^1.6.1",
    "memory-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "mongo-dot-notation": "^1.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.13.0",
    "mongoose-history": "0.8.0",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.8.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "stack-trace": "0.0.10",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
    "useragent": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  }

